# Vuetify VDataTable handle items per page update

Tags: vuetify.js, jsx, v-data-table

I have some paginated data from the backend that I need to fill in `VDataTable`, such as in the following:

```js
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <VDataTable
          headers={this.headers}
          items={this.items || []}
          loading-text='Loading... Please wait'
          loading={this.$apollo.queries.items.loading}
          page={this.page}
          server-items-length={this.total}
        />
      </div >
    );
  }
```

And I need to handle actions like when items per page or page is updated.

But I have not found the documentation on how to do this. The closest I got was [the official Vuetify reference](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#server-side-paginate-and-sort) but they document using template, i.e. `<v-data-table>` instead of `<VDataTable>`. How can I do this in the above JSX way?

Probably something like?

```
onItemsPerPageUpdate={this.handleItemsPerPageUpdate}
onUpdatePage={this.handlePageUpdate}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could define a variable in your data method: `itemsPerPage`, add `:items-per-page="itemsPerPage"` on your data table component and then add a watcher on that variable?

Comment: yeah thats what I did, but I want to utilize the default rows per page selector and page navigation buttons that come with VDataTable, and to use these I will need to register the handlers to the corresponding props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution after some research.

The prop `onPagination` will register event handler listening for pagination change from the default footer, e.g. change of rows per page, change of page number.

You will need to register a handler function that takes in a parameter in this [structure](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#pagination).

Example code as follows, works for vuetify 2.0.

```js
methods: {
  handlePageUpdate(options: any): any {
    this.page = options.page;
    this.pageSize = options.itemsPerPage;
  },
},

data() {
  items: [],
  total: 0, // total number of unpaged entries
  page: 1,
  pageSize: 10,
},

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <VDataTable
        headers={this.headers}
        items={this.items}
        page={this.page}
        server-items-length={this.total || 0}
        onPagination={this.handlePageUpdate}
        footerProps={{'items-per-page-options': [10,20,30]}} // sets custom rows-per-page dropdown options
      />
    </div >
  );
},
```